# expect vs. bash read

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to use `expect` to talk to a `bash` script, but I'm missing something. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "foo? "
read
echo $REPLY
```

and my `expect` script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./script.sh
expect "foo? "
send "bar\r\n"
```

But I never see `bar` when I run the `expect` script. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need to send the `\n`, just the `\r` -- you're simulating "hitting enter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb me, I needed to add `interact` to my `expect` script so that it can finish "interacting" with the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./script.sh
expect "foo? "
send "bar\r\n"
interact
```

I found the answer [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) two minutes after asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't familiar well with `expect` syntax, but you worth try `autoexpect`:

```
autoexpect ./script.sh
```

It will run `script.sh` and after you'll finish running it an expect script `script.exp` will be created in current directory.

After than you can edit it if you need to tune something in it.